# Find common multipler to convert array of decimals as close as possible to a whole number

Tags: python, arrays, math

I have a numpy array of weights of about length 10:

weight_np = [1.56789, 2.1234, ...]

I need to find a common multipler which converts all the weights to integers (or as close as feasibly possible). I know that you can use the GCD to find a common multipler if you want all the array inputs to be integers, but I'm unsure how to go about this is you allow for an 'error' margin of say +- 0.1?

Are there any algorithms I can use to do this?

Comment: It is *always* possible to convert them all to exact integers, just multiply each by 2**53!

Comment: You can ignore my flip comment above, it doesn't work for numbers very close to zero.  But the idea remains, the way floating point numbers are put together it's always possible to get an exact integer out of them.

Comment: What do you mean by "an 'error' margin of say +- 0.1"? 0.1 %, or what exactly?

Comment: @MC Jong, if the values are [1.56789e100, 2.1234e100, ...], the GCD may be quite large.  You want that too?

Comment: If you multiply an element by an array of numbers, then one can assume that, on average, one in 5 of those values will have decimals between .9 and .1. If you do the same for 2 elements, then approx. 1 in 5^2=25 will have decimals between .9 and .1 for both. If you have 10, then it's 5^10 = 9765625. You could brute force that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use brute force as mentioned in the comments.  If you don't require the *minimum* multiplier, it's actually quite easy.

```
def near_int(nparr):
    multiplier = 1
    while True:
        scaled = nparr * multiplier
        rounded = np.rint(scaled)
        if np.allclose(scaled, rounded, atol=0.100000000001, rtol=0):
            return multiplier, scaled
        multiplier *= 10

weight_np = np.array([1.56789, 2.1234, 3.14, 9.11])
near_int(weight_np)
(10000, array([15678.9, 21234. , 31400. , 91100. ]))
```

The tolerance is just a bit higher than 0.1 to allow for floating point inaccuracy.

I went with a strategy that kept the multiplier at a power of 10, because that makes for results that are easier to understand.  But you can use any other method you'd like.